# webdev.webserver20.exe has stopped working

Tags: c#, webserver

I got a pop up window when i'm running one of my asp.net web service project.

What can I do?

I got an error:

WebDev.WebServer.exe has stopped working.

then

Unable to connect to ASP.NET Development Server.

I'm currently using visual studio 2010 on windows 8.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this happening multiple times even after rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please trying rebuilding your application and then run.

If that doesn't work, please kill all processes like  WebDev.WebServer in task manager & then run.

If that doesn't work too, try solutions mentioned at:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1583577.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/72542/webdev-webserver-exe

[adding/removing a file in VS2010 causes "WebDev.WebServer20.exe has stopped working" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344652/adding-removing-a-file-in-vs2010-causes-webdev-webserver20-exe-has-stopped-work)

One thing that bugs me out here is that you are getting process name webdev.webserver20.exe but for same case (visual studio 2010 on windows 8) I am getting process name webdev.webserver40.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same error which was due to code issue.

1. Check if your code has any infinite loops
2. Check if the Garbage collection is handled properly.

   GC.SuppressFinalize

Above code was throwing argumentNullException which was causing webserver to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the target framework in web.config file 
it works good .....